# AutoHotkey scrip for horizontal scrolling in excel not working for graphs

Tags: microsoft-excel, autohotkey

I am using this script for horizontal scrolling using shift + mousewheel for excel:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class XLMAIN
+WheelDown::ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveWindow.SmallScroll(0,0,3,0)
+WheelUp::ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveWindow.SmallScroll(0,0,0,3)
```

It works great for tables but when I hold shift and scroll on graph sheets, I get this error:

```
Error 0x800A03EC -
Source: Microsoft Excel
Description: Unable to get the SmallScroll proprety of the Window class
HelpFile: xlmain11.chm
HelpContext: 0

Specifically: SmallScroll

        Line#
        002: Return
--->    002:
 ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveWindow.SmallScroll(0,0,3,0)
        002: Return
        003:
 ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveWindow.SmallScroll(0,0,3,0)
        003: Return
        004: Exit
        004: Exit
        004: Exit
```

Is there any way to fix this or will I forever be dragging the scroll bar because Excel's ux sucks?

I am using Excel 2016 on Windows 10.

Comment: Get a proper mouse with a scrollwheel that does left/right scrolling as well as vertical scrolling and you won't have this issue.  That being said, I'm stealing your code to try it out.

Comment: On a side note, isn't the SmallScroll method telling Excel how many rows or columns you want to scroll?  And why might one expect that to work on a graph?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but here is an answer for those who are looking for horizontal scrolling in excel.

The AutoHotKey script below works. I did some testing in Excel 2010 and it still scrolls fine on worksheets with Charts. If you have data in the chart selected, it actually will scroll along the data, which is interesting, if unexpected. However it will scroll horizontally as normal as long as you dont have the data in the chart selected.
Hope this helps!

```
#Singleinstance Force

;Horizontal scrolling in Excel only
#IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN

    +WheelUp:: 
        SetScrollLockState, On 
        SendInput {Left} 
        SetScrollLockState, Off 
    Return 

    +WheelDown:: 
        SetScrollLockState, On 
        SendInput {Right} 
        SetScrollLockState, Off 
    Return 
    
; Horizontal scrolling in everything except Excel. 
#IfWinNotActive ahk_class XLMAIN 

    +WheelDown::WheelRight
    +WheelUp::WheelLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the script above to be clumsy and slow: basically sends a set number of {Left} or {Right} commands. None of the AHK solutions seem to be reliable.

This program at GitHub works exceptionally well for horizontal scrolling both Excel and Word 2016 https://github.com/T800G/OfficeScroll
Just press Shift and spin the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

use if to judge the type of activesheet, worksheet is -4167, chart is 3.

```
    #if WinActive("ahk_exe excel.exe")
        +wheelup:: ;scroll left
            xl := Excel_Get()
            if xl.ActiveSheet.Type = -4167
                xl.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll(0,0,0,3)
            return

        +wheeldown:: ;scroll right
            xl := Excel_Get()
            if xl.ActiveSheet.Type = -4167
                xl.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll(0,0,3,0)
            return
        #if
```

or u can use scrolllock instead

```
    #if WinActive("ahk_exe excel.exe")
        +wheelup:: ;scroll left
            SetScrollLockState, alwayson
            send {right 3}
            SetScrollLockState, alwaysoff
            return

        +wheeldown:: ;scroll right
            SetScrollLockState, alwayson
            send {left 3}
            SetScrollLockState, alwaysoff
            return
        #if
```

Comment: You forgot to include the Excel_Get() function: https://github.com/ahkon/MS-Office-COM-Basics/blob/master/Examples/Excel/Excel_Get.ahk

Answer (score 0):

```
Ctrl + Shift + Scroll
```

This works natively in Office 365. Better than the autohotkey solution, a lot more responsive.

I prefer to remap this to make it work without holding down Ctrl key. (Optional)

```
; Shift + Scroll

;Horizontal scrolling in Excel only
#IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN
    +WheelUp:: 
        Send ^+{WheelUp}
    Return 

    +WheelDown:: 
        Send ^+{WheelDown}
    Return 
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: no need to install additional software